# How to add a tag on an existing string in beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, tags

I want to apply an underline tag between two nodes of tags.

`original_tag = <p>The correct answer is <strong>China:</strong></p>`

`Desired Output = <p>The correct answer is <u><strong>China:</strong></u></p>`

I tried this,

```
correctoptions = [x for x in correctoptions if x.name == "p"]
for x in correctoptions:
   new_tag = soup.new_tag("u")
   x.strong.insert(0, new_tag)
```

Comment: Post your complete code. Or at-least a version of it which reproduces the issue.

Comment: Done, there is actually no errors but just my ignorance

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
import copy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("<p>The correct answer is <strong>China:</strong></p>", "html.parser")
# we modify soup object by 'append', so need to use a copy of it to find "strong" tag separately
soup_copy = copy.deepcopy(soup)
u_tag = soup.new_tag("u")
u_tag.append(soup_copy.find("strong"))
soup.find("strong").replaceWith(u_tag)

print(soup)
```

gives `soup` as:

```
<p>The correct answer is <u><strong>China:</strong></u></p>
```

This gives a general idea on how to start, you can modify the above logic as per your needs.

Comment: I am getting this error ont his ```RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object```

Comment: The code I posted works perfectly, take care about using soup and try to do it as close to the code I posted as possible.

Comment: I completed the same thing with ```soup.strong.wrap("u")```, thank you for your help though

Comment: Great. I will checkout the `wrap` method.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using `soup.strong.wrap(soup.new_tag("u"))`

Comment: You mean `soup.strong.wrap(soup.new_tag("u"))`? Also you should accept this answer to mark the issue as resolved.

Comment: Yes i will accept after 2 days since SO says so